# Mouse scrollwheel in Flash/Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, scroll, mouse, scrollbar

I'm building an application in Flex and I have few windows with scroll. When I'm trying to use mouse scrollwheel the window does not scroll up/down. Plus if it is possible to make the window to scroll up/down then is it possible to make to scroll right/left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in as3 there is a mouseevent.mouse_wheel event. Listening for this will yield property delta. the delta property wil tell you if your mousewheel is scrolling up or down. unfortunately this doesnt work with macs. Fortunately, there are some classes out there [internet land] that address this.
re the second bit, side to side, i imagine you could harness an up/down motion to move a scroller left/right, but i dont think thats what your after.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. 
This guy made it possible. Some examples and explaination: http://blog.pixelbreaker.com/flash/as30-mousewheel-on-mac-os-x/